# AJAX Post Multiple Arrays

Tags: ajax

I have 2 input fields like so

```
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[games]"/>
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[art]"/>
```

I want to submit via AJAX, but I'm unsure how to exactly send this data. I know in my controller that I can validate the typeDetails array like typeDetails.games or typeDetails.art, but I'm unsure how to send it.

Here's what my JS looks like currently.

```
var data = { 'typeDetails[]' : []};

$("input[name='typeDetails[games]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[games]'].push($(this).val());
}); 

$("input[name='typeDetails[art]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[art]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

The error I'm getting is "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'typeDetails[games]' and 'typeDetails[art]' are not the keys of data.

Declare data like this

```
var data = { 'typeDetails[games]' : [],  'typeDetails[art]' : []};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like

```
var data = new Array();
$("input[name=typeDetails]").each(function() {
    data.push($(this).val());
});
```